# Is it possible to rent an apartment in Denmark without a CPR number?

Tags: housing, denmark

Do you always need a Danish CPR number in order to rent an apartment in Denmark? Is it possible to finalise a rental agreement from abroad, i.e. when you do not yet have a CPR number?